# BASH:How Grep and display a set of values

Tags: shell-script, grep, ls

In a sample log message we have

```
20161110-15:29:39.707932513|8=FIX.4.29=031735=D34=00000389552=20161110-15:29:39.70749=413050=11156=DDG109=4130115=EAGLE7|EAGLE7116=eagle_fix_trader11|eagle_fix_trader11144=DAU|E7T9139=eagle_fix_trader119195=U439=805440=150854029208=221=1167=FUT55=14198040=259=054=111=41301110400144=0000035.0000000038=00000000760=20161110-15:29:39.70710=092
```

from the above how can you display only the 9139 value so it looks like

```
9139=eagle_fix_trader11
```

I used the below command

```
ls | grep -Eo '9139=[a-z]{0,8}' 9707le8.log
```

But I only get

```
9139=eagle
```

instead of

```
9139=eagle_fix_trader11
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the string after '9139=' always the same length? Is the string after eagle_fix_trader11 always 9195? You can do grep -Eo '9139=[a-z_]+[[:digit:]]{2}', but that will not work for strings that have more than 2 digits at the the end. Ex. if the string was eagle_fix_trader9972, you would only get eagle_fix_trader99.

Comment: no, the string could be a different length

Comment: `grep -o '9139=[0-9a-z_]+' /path/to/input`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti the OP only wants the 1st two digits after `[a-z_]+`. Or so I am assuming, anyway. DjOlu, please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to match. You said the string can be a different length. OK, then tell us what can change and what will always be the same. How can we tell you how to find something if you don't tell us what you are trying to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `ls |` there is completely useless. You want to search inside the file `9707le8.log`, not in the list of files and directoris in your current directory (which is what `ls` prints). In any case, `grep` ignores any input piped to it (`| grep`) when it is also given a file name to search for on the command line as you have.

That said, your regular expression means "find the string `9139=`, followed by <= 8 lower case letters". However, there are only 5 letters after the `=`; the 6th character is an `_` and that isn't part of the `[a-z]` character group. A simple solution is to add it to the class:

```
$ grep -Eo '9139=[a-z_]{0,8}' 9707le8.log
9139=eagle_fi
```

Now, since you want `9139=eagle_fix11`, you need to increase the characters:

```
$ grep -Eo '9139=[a-z_]{0,18}' 9707le8.log
9139=eagle_fix_trader
```

This time, the problem is that you're not matching the numbers since `[a-z_]` doesn't include them. So, you want something like this:

```
$ grep -Eo '9139=[a-z_0-9]{0,18}' 9707le8.log
9139=eagle_fix_trader11
```

Or, for a more general case, where you want `9139=` by a string of lower case letters or `_` and then two numbers, you can use:

```
$ grep -Eo '9139=[a-z_]+[0-9]{2}' 9707le8.log
9139=eagle_fix_trader11
```

Or, with GNU grep:

```
$ grep -Po '9139=[a-z_]+\d{2}' 9707le8.log
9139=eagle_fix_trader11
```